# Getting error message "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Tags: objective-c

I keep getting this error message. Does this somehow need to be converted into a NSString?

[image]

Comment: Just do `query2.limit = theLimit;`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code; they're hard to read and unsearchable. Use copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `query2` object's `limit` property is expecting an NSInteger, and you're providing an NSNumber.

Comment: See [rmaddy's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924005/getting-error-message-incompatible-pointer-to-integer-conversion/16924042?noredirect=1#comment24431692_16924005).